# Cordova Plugin not loading in Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use LokiJS to persistently save data to the phone in an Ionic application. To do so I am using several JS libraries, and we are also using the cordova-file-plugin. However, it seems the callback method (ionic.Platform.ready()) is never firing, and that the plug-in is never being loaded. Any idea what is going on here?

Here is factory code within my `app.js` file for dealing with saving and loading data using LokiJS:

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngStorage', 'lokijs'])

  .factory ('StorageService', function ($localStorage) {

    /**Initiate database 'savedDrawings' with collection 'drawings' and a dynamic view of the names*/
    var db, drawings;
    ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
      // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
      var adapter = new LokiCordovaFSAdapter({"prefix": "loki"});
      db = new loki('loki.json', {
        autosave: true,
        autosaveInterval: 5000,
        autoload: true,
        adapter: adapter
      });
      drawings = db.getCollection('drawings');
      if (!drawings) {
        drawings = db.addCollection('drawings', {
          unique: ['name']
        });
      }
    });



    /**
     * Searches for a creation based on its name and returns it if it exists, prints an error if it does not
     */
    var _get = function (creationName) {
      //return drawings.find({ 'name': creationName });
      var foo =  drawings.by('name', creationName);
      return foo;
    };

    /** TODO
     * Returns all saved creations
     */
    var _getAll = function () {
      return drawings.data;
    };

    /**
     * Adds a creation if one of the same name does not exist
     * Returns -1 if one of the same name does exist
     */
    var _add = function (creation) {
      if(_get(creation.name) != null){
        return -1;
      }

      drawings.insert({
        name: creation.name,
        drawingLines: creation.drawingLines,
        drawingSteps: creation.drawingSteps,
        notesInLine: creation.notesInLine
      });

      db.saveDatabase();
    };

    /**
     * Overwrites a creation by removing and then adding
     */
    var _overwrite = function(creation){
      _remove(creation.name);
      _add(creation);
    };

    /**
     * Searches for a creation based on name and removes it
     */
    var _remove = function (creationName) {
      var drawingToRemove = _get(creationName);
      drawings.remove( drawingToRemove );
    };

    /**
     * Deletes all saved creations
     */
    var _removeAll = function () {
      drawings.removeDataOnly();
    };

    /**
     * These are the function names that can be called by outside functions using StorageService.(function name)
     */
    return {
      getAll: _getAll,
      get: _get,
      add: _add,
      remove: _remove,
      removeAll: _removeAll,
      overwrite: _overwrite
    };
    })
```

And here is my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/drawing.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/result.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" />

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

    <script src="js/drawing.js"></script>
    <script src="js/music_player.js"></script>
    <script src="js/coverConfetti.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="js/wad-master/build/wad.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Loki Libraries -->
    <script src="lib/lokijs/src/lokijs.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/lokijs/src/loki-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/loki-cordova-fs-adapter/bin/loki-cordova-fs-adapter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar ng-controller="resultCtrl" class="bar-dark">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: From first look of the code, i guess the possible problem is with the inclusion of cordova.js file. cordova.js file gets generated in the project root folder on platform build and not under 'js' folder. Hope it helps

Comment: It looks like it is within the platform's www directory for me

Comment: Maybe I need to include cordova_plugins.js? I didn't see that file before.

Comment: cordova_plugins.js inclusion is not required. you just need to change your cordova.js include from <script src="js/cordova.js"></script> to '<script src="cordova.js"></script>'

Comment: please include `ng-cordova.min.js` and inject the dependency `ngCordova` in `.run` method of `app.js` file